# Запись звука с колонок c#

Tags: c#, аудио

Подскажите пожалуйста как записать звук из колонок на c#. Нашел только способ записи с микрофона с помощью NAudio

Comment: А как по твоему колонки должны записывать звук, если их задача - его выводить? Либо я не правильно понял суть вашего вопроса.

Comment: Нужно записать звук который воспроизводится в колонках в аудиофайл.

Comment: Ясно, посмотрите [это](https://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=308485)

Comment: @h4cktivist Буквально с колонок, конечно, нельзя записать звук. Но для записи звука, который ОС выводит на аудиоустройство, существует [WasapiLoopbackCapture](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/WasapiLoopbackCapture.md)